# How the division of work happens inside Akka framework

Tags: java, multithreading, akka, fork-join

Akka uses Fork/Join under the hood. I am interested in the algorithm of how the division of work for execution happens in Akka framework. This is done transparently, I want to use this idea in my java framework for work-stealing based on akka's idea.

Note that I use JDK 7.

Comment: Routers pick an actor reference, dispatchers schedule the execution of an actor's mailbox, and the mailbox processes messages by deque'ing them and invoking the actor. See the [dispatch code](https://github.com/akka/akka/tree/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/dispatch), in particular `Dispatch#dispatch` and Mailbox#run`.

Comment: @Ben Manes Thanks Ben! Turns out, Mailbox.scala extends usual ForkJoinTask behind the scenes that has its run() method.